# (Error 3071) Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm trying to search for the Course ID by checking the the faculty ID and Course ID in my Course table. Its a simple query but when launched I receive a

(This expression is typed incorrectly, or it is too complex to be evaluated. For example, a numeric expression may contain too many complicated elements. Try simplifying the expression by assigning parts of the expression to variables. (Error 3071)

The VB script I'm using looks like this.

```
Private Sub Course_ID_DblClick(Cancel As Integer)

Dim x As Integer

Dim y As String

Dim z As Integer

x = Me.Faculty_ID.Value

Me.Course_ID.RowSource = "SELECT Course.[Course ID] FROM Course WHERE Course.[Course Name]=['Course']AND Course.[Faculty ID]='" & x & "'"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting this message because you are using wrong delimiters and confusing terminology in object names (where field content 'course' and table name [course] are the same.

I guess your datasource is an ms-access database. You should then use the " (double quote) as value separator (you'll have to double the sign inside the expression) for text, and nothing for numbers. your select instruction could then look like:

```
"SELECT Course.[Course ID] FROM Course WHERE Course.[CourseName]=[""Course""] AND Course[FacultyID]=" & x
```

Add a 'debug.print Me.Course_ID.RowSource' to check the final string that should look like:

```
SELECT Course.[Course ID] FROM Course WHERE Course.[CourseName]=["Course"] AND Course[FacultyID]= 3
```

Comment: Avcess supports either the single or double quote as a string delimiter in a query

Answer (score 0):

There should be no brackets around your string literals:

```
Me.Course_ID.RowSource = "SELECT Course.[Course ID] FROM Course WHERE Course.[Course Name]='xyz' AND ...
```

Also, you can use either single or double quotes as string delimiters in an access query.